# PHP Redirect - Hide referrer over a HTTPS connection

Tags: php, ssl, https, http-referer

On my website I want to be able to blank the referrer in order to not reveal where my traffic is coming from.

Here is an example:

```
Site 1 - http://www.examplesite1.com (traffic source)
Site 2 - https://www.examplesite2.com (site to redirect through, notice it is redirecting over a SSL connection)
Site 3 - http://www.partnerssite.com (where i want to push traffic from examplesite1.com, the "referer" header should be dropped, because it is redirecting from a HTTP Secure to a Non-secure HTTP)
```

I have the following code inside Site 1:

```
<?php 
header("Location: https://redirect/to/site2");
?>
```

And inside the Site 2:

```
<?php 
header("Location: http://www.partnerssite.com");
?>
```

BUT everytime i run the script, the referrer from "Site 1" keeps getting leaked.

Can you help me solve this problem? All help and tips are very welcome.

thanks

Comment: I believe that 301 redirects will always pass the referer.